# Separar texto em duas colunas

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma div que irá conter duas colunas. 
Conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma técnica em CSS para fazer isso? Não CSS3, pois quero que funcione em todos os navegadores.

Claro, eu poderia criar duas divs ali e colocar `float:left` mas irá se tratar de um conteúdo só, quando o usuário está digitando na coluna esquerda e termina, ele vai para a direita.

Meu HTML está assim:

```
<div class="grid_480 f-left margin-top-60 margin-bottom-60"></div>
```

O CSS:

```
.grid_480{width:480}
.margin-top-60{margin-top:60px}
.margin-bottom-60{margin-bottom:60px}
.f-left{float:left}
```

Comment: Se queres fazer isso só com uma div duvido que consigas

Comment: Não consegui heheheeh, por isso vou ver se alguém daqui sabe.

Comment: Com duas div's consegues dividir o conteúdo, se quiseres posso fazer um exemplo

Comment: O que acontece, é que essas colunas serão gerenciáveis. Ou seja, quando o cliente estiver digitando o conteúdo, o texto da esquerda acaba e ele começa na direita, como é no Word.

Comment: Ahh já estou a entender. Não sei se consigo fazer então, mas vou tentar

Comment: Valeu @CesarMiguel

Comment: Sem JavaScript, nada me passa pela cabeça, mas se isso for permissível tenho uma ideia: crie duas divs, e faça com que uma seja um "espelho" da outra (i.e. se uma muda, a outra muda igual); faça com que ambas tenham `overflow: hidden`, altura o dobro do espaço visível e posicione-as de modo que uma exiba a parte superior, e a outra a parte inferior. Se quiser eu tento montar um exemplo (mas se seu requisito é só CSS, então não adianta).

Comment: Cara, estava pesquisando na net e só ficará funcional com CSS3 mesmo. Quem usa IE7/8 que se conforme, hehe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não, exclusivamente com CSS2 não existe, mas o CSS3 não é tão incompatível assim, e você pode elaborar um layout/script alternativo para navegadores obsoletos com a linguagem que você conhecer melhor.

Com CSS3, bastaria:

```
.div-em-colunas {
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:2;    /* Firefox */
    column-count:2;         /* padrão */
}
```